# Limit trigger_error to class scope

Tags: php, logging, error-handling

I am currently writing a plugin that is security related. This means that visibility and accessibility of methods and properties are even more important. I am using a lot of getters and setters and permission checking to prevent unauthorized access. However, to give users who are allowed to use the plugin more control, I would like to implement a "security log". There should, for example, be logged when the public method `requestDBHandler()` was accessed, since it is only used for external access by other plugins. Also, some actions like deletion or moving should be logged. This logging should be only accessible from within the plugin class so that it can not be manipulated or faked from outside (which sense would it make to have the log if this would be possible).

What I thought of first was a logger class that handles the logging, but this means that I have to inject it as dependency in all child classes that could have the need to log something. Also this creates, even if I use an interface, tight coupling because all users of this class must know the functions to push to the log.

The second thought was `trigger_error()`, but up to now I found no way of setting the error-handling function only for one class and all its members. Even then, errors logged can have no custom error types so I could not distinguish between code errors/notices I throw and things that are supposed to be for pure logging. Also, it would feel wrong to use `trigger_error()` for something that is not really an error.

Could you recommend a good way of implementing this logging system? How would you do it? I know that this is a bit widely asked and gives room for discussion, but I also believe that there is a clear and correct best-practice answer to this problem.

Comment: _“This logging should be only accessible from within the plugin class so that it can not be manipulated or faked from outside”_ – so where do you want to store that log data – in a file, a database table, …? You would first of all have to apply/implement access control to those resources, otherwise any other script/plugin could write data to that location as well, without even using your logging code.

Comment: Sure, but thats another topic. I currently plan to store the data encrypted in the database

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion from top of my head would be to go with injecting standard [PSR-3 `LoggerInterface`](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md).

If your child classes are going to log anything then I guess it's not unreasonable to expect that they should do it via (injected?) PSR-3 `LoggerInterface` instance anyway.

If your child classes works with standard PSR-3 `LoggerInterface` and your "container" gives them your specific PSR-3 `LoggerInterface` implementation then I guess it's not tight coupling.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that a PSR-3 standard for Loggers exists. This is definitely a good solution for my problem. I will keep the question open for now just in case someone can think if a way without dependency injection.